# Filling a list recursively

Tags: prolog

I want to write a rule to exhaust the database and fill a list with some items but the prolog interpreter always returns with: Out of global stack.

```
fill(SomeParams, List) :- append(List, [NewItem], List), fail.
```

Is there a way to extend a list without doing unification?

Comment: use findall/3. Or findall/4 for more advanced options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `append` can't work because it states that `List` is the result of appending `[NewItem]`to `List`, so `List` is supposed to be two things at once. Remember, variables in Prolog are logical variables that can never be changed, once they are bound.

You can use [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3), as CapelliC said, or if you want more control, you can do something like this:

```
%% some facts
fact(1).
fact(2).
fact(3).

fill(List, NewList) :-
    fact(X),
    not(member(X, List)), !,
    fill([X|List], NewList).
fill(List, List).

%%
fill(NewList) :- fill([], NewList).
```

Then

```
try ?- fill(L).
```