# Definitions of some keywords/predicates

Tags: prolog

Can someone give me definitions of some keywords/predicates in Prolog please?

- Parse-time
- `bagof`
- `findall`
- the `^` predicate
- the `@` predicate

for example, `bagof(X, Y^place(X, Y , japan), Xs)`,
`A<@B`,
`A>@B`.

can someone please give me the meaning of these predicates and any other that might be quite useful, I have a good interest in Prolog but due to my job I can't afford to give Prolog too much of my time. I have quite good knowledge in Prolog but it just I can't seem to find out the meaning of some words .

Comment: See for `(^)/2`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931801/what-is-the-prolog-operator/19931970#19931970

Answer (score 2):

All that you need seems to be well documented, for example for GNU-Prolog:

- [bagof](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec114) (also explains `(^)/2`)
- [findall](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec113)
- [@ comparison
  predicates](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#%28==%29/2)

And [`parse_time` in SWI-Prolog documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=parse_time/3)

Answer (score 2):

See the links that @jkbkot gave for the complete descriptions. By way of very brief and very narrow examples:

---

**`parse_time`** (note spelling - SWI Prolog predicate)

```
?- parse_time('Fri, 08 Dec 2006 15:29:44 GMT', Format, Time).
Format = rfc_1123,
Time = 1165591784.0.

?- parse_time('2013-10-12', Format, Time).
Format = iso_8601,
Time = 1381536000.0.
```

Using this, you can get a numerical representation of date/time and manage them numerically. The date string is a required input parameter (must be instantiated). So, unfortunately, `parse_time` isn't useful for converting formats back and forth.

```
?- parse_time(D, iso_8601, 1381536000.0).
ERROR: atom_codes/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

---

**`bagof`** and **`^`**

```
likes(a,b).
likes(a,c).
likes(a,d).
likes(b,c).
likes(b,e).

?- bagof(X, likes(X,Y), L).
Y = b,
L = [a] ;
Y = c,
L = [a, b] ;
Y = d,
L = [a] ;
Y = e,
L = [b].

?- bagof(X, Y^likes(X,Y), L).
L = [a, a, a, b, b]

?- bagof(X-Y, likes(X,Y), L).
L = [a-b, a-c, a-d, b-c, b-e].

?- setof(X, Y^likes(X,Y), L).   % provides the unique, sorted results
L = [a, b]

?- setof(X-Y, likes(X,Y), L).
L = [a-b, a-c, a-d, b-c, b-e].
```

---

**`findall`**

```
likes(a,b).
likes(a,c).
likes(a,d).
likes(b,c).
likes(b,e).

?- findall(X, likes(X,Y), L).
L = [a, a, a, b, b].

?- findall(X-Y, likes(X,Y), L).
L = [a-b, a-c, a-d, b-c, b-e].
```

---

**`@`**

The most common use of this symbol is in comparison predicates `@</2`, `@>/2`, etc. Example expressions of `A<@B` and `A>@B` are Prolog syntax errors.

```
?- 1 < 2.
true.

?- X=1, Y=2, X+Y<5.
true.

?- a < b.
ERROR: </2: Arithmetic: `a/0' is not a function

?- a @< b.
true.

?- a @> b.
false.

?- a < 1.
false.

?- [2,3,4] @< [2,3,5].
true.

?- [2,3,4] @< [2,3,3].
false.

?- foo(a,X) @< foo(b,Y).
true.

?- foo(b,X) @< foo(a,Y).
false.
```

Using `@<` you don't necessarily have to use `parse_time` if you want to compare date/time strings as long as their chronological order follows ASCII lexicographical order:

```
?- '2013-11-09' @< '2013-12-01'.
true.

?- '2013-01-12' @< '2012-12-12'.
false.
```

The `@` comparison predicates can be quite handy. :)

Comment: In fact, `@`/2 is a predicate (or if you like control construct) in SWI and IF to manipulate the module context.

Comment: Thanks @false I totally missed that. I spend too much time in GNU Prolog (although I strove to give examples above in SWI). :)

Comment: Hi @mbratch, how did you, for example print this in a list bagof(X, Y^likes(X,Y), L).
L = [a, a, a, b, b]?

Comment: @KennD that's how it works. Did you try it?

Comment: @ mbratch, sorry, what I meant to ask was, how can you create a rule for a list? without using built in functions such as bagof or findall.

Comment: @KennD that's a totally different question that you could submit in SO. If you look through SO [Prolog] section, there have been several responses to that type of question already. It's not a simple comment answer.

Comment: Could you please give me a link to the SO [Prolog] section please.

Comment: @KennD there are several if you just search for them. Most of them indicate use of `findall`. Here's a combination: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825218/how-to-create-a-list-of-numbers-that-add-up-to-a-specific-number

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am looking for quite something different. The link you provided, although says how to use a list but I want to learn how to create a rule that prints given item in a database in a list e.g. names, numbers or characters

Comment: @KennD, here's another interesting post, which works for certain scenarios: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925428/filling-a-list-recursively/20927294#20927294

Comment: @KennD and another nice, simple case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041164/using-cuts-in-prolog-to-select-facts-from-database