# Using cuts in prolog to select facts from database

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I'm supposed to use Prolog cuts to get the first , the second and the last fact from the facts database , I found a way to get the first and the second but I can't find a solution for retrieving the last fact  here is an example :

```
P(jack).
P(john).
P(alice).
P(sarah).
P(kyle).
```

Selecting the first fact only : `first(X):-P(X),!.`

Selecting the second fact only : `second(Y):-P(X),P(Y),X\=Y,P(Y),!.`

Selecting the last fact only : ?

Comment: In your example, the `P` shouldn't be capital. Words that start with a capital letter are variables. The same goes for the rules as well

Comment: an interesting exercise

Comment: Yes you right , a typo error , thanks for pointing that out .

Comment: Indeed it is @CapelliC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a way without using negation, an accumulator, and the service predicate member, but since negation (by failure) is implemented with cuts, here is my bet:

```
last_(Y) :- collect([], [Y|_]).

collect(Seen, L) :-
    p(X), \+ member(X, Seen), collect([X|Seen], L).
collect(All, All).
```

Instead of `\+ member(Elem,List)` (read Elem is not in List), you could implement a not_contains/2, with explicit cut inside.

BTW your second/1 predicate contains a redundant call: should be

```
second(Y):-p(X),p(Y),X\=Y,!.
```

Comment: Your code is working great , except it gave possibilities to visit other facts not only the last one but thanks a lot :D

Comment: I added a cut the last_(Y) and it worked like a charm : last_(Y) :- collect([], [Y|_]),!. i still don't get this cut stuff anyway .